# How can I find all encrypted and/or signed emails in outlook?

Tags: search, microsoft-outlook-2013

How can I find those emails and is it possible to make a search folder containing those emails?

I tried several fields and tried to make a search folder, but found no attribute for this search.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The criteria for a custom search folder would be (Search Folder Criteria | "Advanced" tab | "Field" button | All Mail Fields):

- **Message Class** contains **IPM.Note.SMIME** (for both signed/encrypted messages);
- **Message Class** is (exactly) **IPM.Note.SMIME** (for encrypted messages only);
- **Message Class** is (exactly) **IPM.Note.SMIME.MultipartSigned** (for signed messages only that are not encrypted).

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly, except for all emails which are in our enterprise archiving system. :( But that was not part of my question :)

Comment: @Arister, btw what archiving system do you use? Symantec EV?

Comment: Yes, Symantec EV. It appears to shield some attributes from beeing searched after.